# 4TB drives only show as 2T in Windows server 2016

Tags: windows, hard-drive, gpt

I have some 4T SATA drives in GPT, they only be detected as 2T drive under Windows server 2016, but they all be seen as full capacity = 4T under FreeNAS.

All the hardware configuration is the same, drives are connected to SATA Ports. Difference is OS only.

I am not sure if this is an issue with SATA controller or an issue with drive itself. I have tried 3 party utilities, reset the drives, convert to GPT and so on, the issue remains the same. Windows wont see the full capacity of those drives.

Anyone had similar issue before?

Comment: Did you complete the OS install already?  Are you sure you are booting your OS Install from media in UEFI mode?

Comment: I finished OS install. OS boots from BIOS on a 120G SSD. Those large drives are for data.

Comment: Hrm, if they are just for data drives, you would normally expect things to 'just work'.  Sorry, not sure what to suggest.

Comment: It's a little strange that you couldn't install with UEFI. No, a lot strange. If that motherboard really won't support UEFI, it might be too old to be worth using. If you installed without using UEFI, you probably should format and reinstall.

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the disk to a GPT disk in Windows before you can assign a 4TB partition.

Open up the disk management and right-click on the disk in question, then click on "Initialize to GPT Disk" or "Convert MBR Disk to GPT Disk" if you already have a partition/data on it.  Wait for it to finish... and you should be able to create a new 4tb partition, or resize the current partition larger (within constraints of block-size & such)

Comment: Thanks for the info, as my first line stats they are configured as GPT.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved.

It is the SATA controller on board was not supported by Win2016 but FreeNAS. I installed a extra SATA controller, they all showing as 4TB now.

Comment: glad you got it working!  Could you please tell us what kind of SATA controller it is?  Might be useful for others in the future.

Comment: I just bought an SATA extender card with 8 ports, not a controller. it supports SATA3 but no RAID support. That's it.